# Different numbers for CHMOD -R 777

Tags: chmod, 777

Does somebody know what other numbers to use for sudo chmod -R 777 .
I only want to recursively to change read and write permissions. But not to make them executable. Anybody knows the number to use instead of 777

?

Comment: 4 for read, 2 for write and 1 for execution.So if yo need only to change read and write permissions : chmod -R 666 .

Answer (score 1):

There are three Classes – Owner, Group, Others.
If you write chmod -R 777, the first '7' defines the permissions of Owner. The second '7' defines the permissions of the group and the last '7' defines the permissions of 'others'.

Read is equivalent to ‘4’.
Write is equivalent to ‘2’.
Execute is equivalent to ‘1’
When we want to set permissions, we just add up the number. For example, to set the permissions to read and write, we will use ‘6’ (4 + 2) for the permission. For read, write and execute, we will use ‘7’ (4 + 2 + 1) for the permission.

For your example use chmod -R 666

Answer (score 0):

Text codes:

> u = user
>   g = group
>   o = other (not user or group)
>   a = all
>   + = add permissions
>   - = remove permissions
>   r = read
>   w = write
>   x = execute
>   t = sticky bit